# python printing regex matches produces empty lists

Tags: python, regex, list

I am using regex to match names proceeding "Dr. ". However, when I print the matches, they print as lists, and some are empty. I'm looking to print just the names.
code:

```
import re

f = open('qwert.txt', 'r')

lines = f.readlines()
for x in lines:
       p=re.findall(r'(?:Dr[.](\w+))',x)
       q=re.findall(r'(?:As (\w+))',x)
       print p
       print q
```

qwert.txt:

```
Dr.John and Dr.Keel
Dr.Tensa
Dr.Jees
As John winning Nobel prize
As Mary wins all prize
car
 tick me 3
 python.hi=is good
 dynamic 
 and precise

tickme 2 and its in it
 its rapid  
 its best
 well and easy
```

desired output:

```
John
Keel
Tensa
Jees
John
Mary
```

actual output:

```
['John', 'Keel']
[]
['Tensa']
[]
['Jees']
[]
[]
['John']
[]
['Mary']
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Comment: What happened to `Jees` in your desired output?

Answer (score 2):

`re.findall()` always returns a list of matches, and that list can be empty. Loop over the result and print each element separately:

```
p = re.findall(r'(?:Dr[.](\w+))', x)
for match in p:
    print match
q = re.findall(r'(?:As (\w+))', x)
for match in q:
    print q
```

Empty lists mean nothing will be printed.

You could even do:

```
for match in re.findall(r'(?:Dr[.](\w+))', x):
    print match
for match in re.findall(r'(?:As (\w+))', x):
    print q
```

and forgo the use of the `p` and `q` variables.

Last but not least, you can combine the regular expressions into one:

```
for match in re.findall(r'(?:Dr\.|As )(\w+)', x):
    print match
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> lines = '''\
... Dr.John and Dr.Keel
... Dr.Tensa
... Dr.Jees
... As John winning Nobel prize
... As Mary wins all prize
... car
...  tick me 3
...  python.hi=is good
...  dynamic 
...  and precise
... 
... tickme 2 and its in it
...  its rapid  
...  its best
...  well and easy
... '''.splitlines(True)
>>> for x in lines:
...     for match in re.findall(r'(?:Dr\.|As )(\w+)', x):
...         print match
... 
John
Keel
Tensa
Jees
John
Mary
```

Answer (score 2):

The `[]` you see are because `findAll` returns a `list` of strings. If you need the strings themselves, iterate over the result of findAll.

```
p=re.findall(r'(?:Dr[.](\w+))',x)
q=re.findall(r'(?:As (\w+))',x)
for str in p+q:
  print str
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply test against the result of `findall` before printing:

```
import re

with open('qwert.txt', 'r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        res = re.findall(r'(?:Dr[.](\w+))', line)
        if res: 
            print '\n'.join(res)
        res = re.findall(r'(?:As (\w+))', line)
        if res:
            print '\n'.join(res)
```

This won't scale nicely if the number of regular expression is more than a couple. A more useful approach maybe:

```
import re 
from functools import partial


def parseNames(regexs, line):
    """
    Returns a newline seperated string of matches given a 
    list or regular expressions and a string to search
    """
    res = ""
    for regex in regexs:
        res += '\n'.join(re.findall(regex, line))
    return res


regexs = [r'(?:Dr[.](\w+))', r'(?:As (\w+))'] 
match = partial(parseNames, regexs)

with open('qwert.txt', 'r') as fh:
    names = map(match, fh.readlines())
    print '\n'.join(filter(None, names))
```

Output:

```
John
Keel
Tensa
Jees
John
Mary
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through your results.

Consider using `findall()` once so it doesn't have to be repeated on each iteration.

```
>>> import re
>>> f = open('qwert.txt', 'r')
>>> for line in f:
...     matches = re.findall(r'(?:Dr\.|As )(\w+)', line)
...     for x in matches:
...         print x

John
Keel
Tensa
Jees
John
Mary
```